# Long Java bit list wanted

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

In Java, I have an array of a million or so flags true/false to store in mind. Should `BitSet` help? Although it implements a `Set`, will it be possible to iterate its elements as fast as if it would be an array `boolean[]`?

Sorry if the question has been asked. First I tried to split an array into chunks of binary represented ints and form `int[]` as a result of those binaries, so I could reduce the size by 32, but this is quite low-level.

I found some critics of the `BitSet` elsewhere and that `boolean[]` stores a lot of extra memory => bad for large arrays.

Any better idea to store a million of flags?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how many will be set to true in the typical case?  A simple `HashSet` or `TreeSet` will take much less memory than either `BitSet` or `boolean[]` if the flags will almost always be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an array of a million or so flags true/false to store in mind. Should BitSet help?

You can have billions of bits in a BitSet.

> Although it implements a Set, will it be possible to iterate its elements as fast as if it would be an array boolean[]?

A boolean[] uses one byte per bit (on most JVMs) whereas BitSet uses one bit per bit.  For small arrays, a boolean[] is faster, but when you are testing the size of your CPU cache a BitSet can be more efficient.

BTW: Using a BitSet is slightly slower for small sizes because it need to extract out a bit out of each a word of memory. A `byte[]` has the same issue, so if you want to set bit yourself, I suggest you use a `int[]` like BitSet does.

---

An example using BitSet

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
// set bit 100
bitSet.set(100);
// get bit 99
System.out.println("bit 99 is " + bitSet.get(99));
System.out.println("bit 100 is " + bitSet.get(100) + " after set");
bitSet.clear(100);
System.out.println("bit 100 is " + bitSet.get(100) + " after clear");
```

prints

```
bit 99 is false
bit 100 is true after set
bit 100 is false after clear
```

Comment: I did it with `int[]` of a pre-specified size and it works faster than `boolean[]`. With a `BitSet` I did not understand how to add elements :) and can not find a good web page to read about its properties. So my choice is `int[]`, hope it is faster than a `BitSet`.

Comment: @SophieSperner Its likely to be the same speed except a BitSet is simpler. To set the n-th bit you call `set(n)` and to get the n-th bit you use `get(n)` perhaps you imagine it to be more complicated than it is. ;)

Comment: @SophieSperner I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use just a simple `boolean[]`.
Also, be careful that `BitSet` does not implement the `Set` interface.

```
public class BitSet implements Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, what about using something like a `HashSet` and add the indices of the flags that are "on", remove them when they turn "off".

(This would work especially well if most of your flags are off at any given time).

Comment: as long as the set is predominantly one way or the other this could be a good solution.  If it's a good mix, then you'll be using much more memory since now instead of bit or boolean in the collection it'll be Integer.

Comment: @digitaljoel Yeah, naively something like a `32 : 1` ratio would make this a "good" solution, as far as memory goes.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

- boolean: The boolean data type has only two possible values: true and
  false. Use this data type for simple flags that track true/false
  conditions. This data type represents one bit of information, but its
  "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.

If you are worried about size and predictability then I would look at trying to represent 8 bit blocks as bytes and then store in a byte[].

Answer (score 0):

`BitSet` operations are quite efficient, you can examine [the sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/BitSet.java) yourself. It doesn't implement `Set`, but you can efficiently iterate over the individual bits in a simple cycle, like:

```
int l = bitSet.length();
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    boolean bit = bitSet.get(i);
    // ...
}
```

(What criticism on `BitSet1 have you found? Please include links in your question for others to see.)

---

If you have a specific, fixed set of boolean flags you need to manage, you could list them in an `enum` and then represent flag settings using [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). Operations on them are also implemented very  efficiently. To quote the docs:

> The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if their argument is also an enum set.

And as an additional benefit compared to `BitSet`s, this representation is [type-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), which can save you a lot of troubles.